# ¿Porque al llamar un fragment a otro me sale la pantalla en blanco y me regresa a mi login?

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenas tardes amigos programadores, estoy trabajando con `fragment` el cual tengo uno como menú principal el cual tiene `CardView` y cuando doy clic en un `CardView` a través de la función `setNavigationOnClickListener` para llamar el otro `fragment`me sale la pantalla en blanco y luego me devuelve al login.

Lo que quise hacer en el otro `fragment` activar el la función de retroceso en el toolbar y le agregue el`setNavigationOnClickListener` la función del `onBackPressed()` no se qu me falto, algo que agregar, ya que no me sale ningún error para poder saber donde esta el detalle.

**menu_fragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_fragment, container, false);
    CardView cardVolcan = view.findViewById(R.id.card_volcan);
    cardVolcan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction fr = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.contenido,new Volcan_popocatepetl());
            fr.commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**volcan_fragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_volcan_popocatepetl, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.retroceso);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

La causa del problema que presentas es causada por `getActivity().onBackPressed();` asegura que no tengas en otro punto de tu Fragment Volcan_popocatepetl, ya que esto provoca que al cargar el Fragment regrese a la Activity anterior en este caso la del Login.